# How to programmatically send additional notification emails in Contact form 7

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

I have a list of emails I have fetched from the Wordpress database.

I would like to programmatically send emails to these emails using the contact form 7.

this is my code

```
function benson_call_before_form_submit( $wpcf7 ){

     $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    if ( $submission ) {
        $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
    }

    if( $wpcf7->id() == 2216 || $wpcf7->id() == "2216" ) {
        //$wpcf->skip_mail = true; 
        // we can now send the email here
        $emails = get_mod_and_admin_emails(); // these are emails

        // how do I send email inside here from contact form 7
        // ?????????????????

    }

}

add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'benson_call_before_form_submit' );

function get_mod_and_admin_emails(  ){
    global $bp; 
    $users = get_users( array( 'fields' => array( 'ID', 'user_email' ) ) );
    $emails = ""; 



    foreach($users as $key => $user){
       $user_id = $user->ID;

       if( groups_is_user_mod( $user_id, $bp->groups->current_group->id ) ||  groups_is_user_admin( $user_id, $bp->groups->current_group->id ) ){
           $email = $user->user_email; 

           $emails .=$email.","; 

       }

    }

    return $emails; 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.

Answer (score 2):

You can manipulate recipients just before sending out the emails with the hook wpcf7_before_send_mail.

Here is a simple script that adds an extra recipient:

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'add_my_second_recipient', 10, 1 );

function add_my_second_recipient($instance) {
    $properites = $instance->get_properties();
    // use below part if you want to add recipient based on the submitted data
    /*
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    $data = $submission->get_posted_data();
    */
    $additional_recipent = 'test@test.com';
    $properites['mail']['recipient'] .= ', ' . $additional_recipent;
        
    $instance->set_properties($properites);
    return ($instance);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is 2 way to achieve this, either

1 use the 'wpcf7_mail_components' hook, to modify the email recipient or cc list,

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_mail_components', 'change_email_address',10,3);
function change_email_address($components, $form, $mailobj){
  //get the $users....
  foreach($users as $key => $user){
    $email = $user->user_email;
    //either as in the recipient list,
    $components['recipient'].=','.$email;
    //or add in cc
    $cc=$email.',';
  }
  $components['additional_headers']='cc:'.$cc;
  return $components;
}
```

2 use the 'wpcf7_additional_mail' to create additional emails,

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_additional_mail', 'send_additional_mails',10,2);
function send_additional_mails($mails, $form){
  //$mails will container the maail_2 template if you have enabled it.
  //reset it if you don't want to send mail_2, but just using it as an additional mail template. 
  $mails = array(); 
  //get the $users....
  foreach($users as $key => $user){
    $email = $user->user_email;
    //copy your mail template
    $template = $form->prop('mail');
    //or if you have enabled mail 2 template, you can use that instead.
    $template = $form->prop('mail_2');
    //add the mail to the recipient list...
    $template['recipient'] = $email ;
    $mails[$email] = $template;
  }
  return $mails;
}
```

Once you have set the templates, you can hook 'wpcf7_mail_components' to further filter your additional mails.